# How to create side by side plots using 2 dataframes with different size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a data set like below (https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqKyz.png). And I need to use the 2 fields 'Date' and 'Price' to create side by side plots like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/a70pI.png)
while the left one is price data with date between 28/02/2022 and 09/03/2023 and the right one is price data with date between 09/03/2023 and 26/04/2023. as the x axis are different for these 2 subplots, is there any way to do that? thanks

my code below doesn't work and it gives me error 'IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed'

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

before_bankrupt = df.loc[df['Date'] < '10/03/2022']
after_bankrupt = df.loc[df['Date'] >= '10/03/2022']
before_bankrupt_plot = before_bankrupt[['Date', 'Price']]
after_bankrupt_plot = after_bankrupt[['Date', 'Price']]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
before_bankrupt_plot.plot(ax=axes[0,0])
after_bankrupt_plot.plot(ax=axes[0,1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code

```
before_bankrupt_plot.plot(ax=axes[0,0])
after_bankrupt_plot.plot(ax=axes[0,1])
```

->

```
before_bankrupt_plot.plot(ax=axes[0])
after_bankrupt_plot.plot(ax=axes[1])
```